# R - Compute a parwise Cohen's d

Tags: r, pairwise

I have two df reporting the means and sd of two groups observed by the same variables.
Now I'd like to compute the Cohen's d to pairwise data.
Do I have to merge the df and then execute the Cohen's d? Or there is just a faster way to do it?
Thank you in advice.

```
tab1<-data.frame(variables=c(1:7),means=c(10.45,40.35,30.15,86.60,5.63,20.81,50.34), 
                 sd=c(2.32,9.51,3.87,17.11,3.45,5.45,4.62))

tab2<-data.frame(variables=c(1:7),means=c(10.38,32.29,27.69,88.74,4.93,13.37,51.50), 
                 sd=c(2.33,10.21,4.59,15.79,3.44,7.16,4.69))
```

Comment: Many packages require raw data for calculating Cohen's d. However, you can calculate it "by hand" through the formula: https://small-s.science/2020/12/cohens-d-for-paired-designs/ Note, it woudl be easier if you would provide your code as a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you calculate by hand with:

```
cohens_d <- (tab1$means - tab2$means) / sqrt(0.5*(tab1$sd + tab2$sd))
```

which gives:

```
[1]  0.04590781  2.56682691  1.19609293 -0.52763163  0.37714072  2.96299139 -0.53764814
```

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. I expected such a specific library for it.

Comment: As i said, there are many packages for calculating Cohen's d, but they usually require the ra, individual data, not the aggregated stats.

Comment: Obviously I have them also. Could you please link those procedures? So I can just learn it. I can paste here raw data if you need it.

Comment: Yes, please paste the raw data. But you might want to do a simply Google search first for "cohens d R". You will come across many packages, e.g. `rstatix`, `lsr` or `effsize´, which you might want to try out. And once you are stuck, you could share the code you've already tried and then we can see where we coudl help a bit more.